# Neo4j Aura does not support apoc.cypher.runSchema

Tags: neo4j, full-text-search, neo4j-apoc

Is there a workaround for this apoc call on neo4j Aura? I need it to be able
to create a fulltext search index.

If I try it with apoc.cypher.run this error occurs:

```
Neo.ClientError.Security.Forbidden 
Schema operations on database 'neo4j' are not allowed for user 'neo4j' with FULL overridden by READ.
```

Neo4j query:

```
CALL db.propertyKeys() YIELD propertyKey 
CALL db.labels() YIELD label 
WITH apoc.text.join(collect(DISTINCT propertyKey), "`, n.`") as properties, apoc.text.join(collect(DISTINCT label), "`|`") AS labels 
CALL apoc.cypher.runSchema("CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX fullSearchIndex FOR(n:`" + labels + "`) ON EACH [n.`"+properties+"`]", {}) YIELD value RETURN value
```

Comment: Can you include what query you run with `apoc.cypher.runSchema`?

Comment: @fbiville Query added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a subset of what APOC offers is available to Aura. See the full list here: https://neo4j.com/docs/aura/platform/apoc/

In your specific case, `apoc.cypher.runSchema` is only useful because you create statements dynamically and run them within a single query.

Since `apoc.cypher.runSchema` cannot be used, you will need to create and run these statements on the client side.

Run first:

```
CALL db.propertyKeys() YIELD propertyKey 
CALL db.labels() YIELD label 
RETURN collect(DISTINCT propertyKey) as properties, collect(DISTINCT label) AS labels
```

Process the results in C# and create the statements there.

Then, you can run the statements one by one.

It's obviously less efficient than doing everything on the server side but I don't think there is a way around it.

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean with move parts of that logic to a client program? We are running our .net C# code in a client program, but with the migration to neo4j Aura we are not able to create the fulltext search index anymore as apoc.cypher.runSchema is not supported by Aura. (Neo4j.Driver Nuget package v4.4.0 in use)

Comment: Oops, right, I should have got the hint from the first sentence. Let me rephrase the answer.

Comment: Ok if I run the collect query I got a list of properties and nodes but how looks like a statement to generate the index one by one? (because everything should be in the index "fullSearchIndex", but if I run the CREATE INDEX queries particular there is an error message that the index already exists) Is there a way to extend the index or how can I solve this? Thx